# Python Unable to load .pkl file into my model with Docker

Tags: docker, deep-learning

## For Learning Purpose

I'm in the process of developing a custom deep learning model using Keras, which isn't a sequential model. This model has a dual output: it generates continuous values for forecasting and multi-class labels for prediction. To streamline my work, I'm utilizing scikit-learn Pipelines and saving the entire pipeline with joblib.

I've come across an issue with scikit-learn's Keras wrapper, which is designed for sequential models. Consequently, I've built my own custom model successfully, and it performs well locally. I've even gone the extra mile by creating a Proof of Concept API and a small website to serve this model.

Everything works smoothly on my local environment. However, when I attempt to build a Docker image, I encounter a problem. The pipeline fails to load the model weights, resulting in an error message like this:

```
Layer 'lstm_cell' expected 3 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['lstm/lstm_cell/kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/bias:0']
```

I'm left wondering if others have faced this situation before. Could there be an issue with handling **.pkl** files in Docker, or is there a need to zip the files before uploading? I've spent a few hours trying to resolve this, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a glimpse of my folder:

```
.
└── END2END/
    ├── pipelines/
    │   ├── scripts
    │   ├── __init__py
    │   └── myscripts.py
    ├── train_models/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── script2.py
    │   └── my_model_.pkl
    ├── api.py
    └── Dockerfile
```

and my model :

```
def ModelLSTM(input_shape, hidden_units: int,
              output_1: int, output_2: int,
              lr: float, model_name: str) -> keras.Model:
    """ LSTM model - single multioutput model
    ### Arguments:
        - input_shape : input shapes
        - hidden_units : hidden units (LSTM units)
        - output_1 : number of outputs (forecasting outputs)
        - output_2 : number of outputs (failures outputs)
        - lr : learning rate
        - name: name of the model
       
    ### Returns:
        model (keras.Model)"""
   
    # Data Input
    inputs_ = keras.Input(
        shape=(input_shape[1], input_shape[2]),
        name='inputs'
    )

    # Lstm Layer
    hiddens_layers = layers.LSTM(hidden_units, return_sequences=True)(inputs_)

    # output forecasting 
    output_forecast = layers.Dense(output_1, activation='linear', name='forecast')(hiddens_layers)

    # output failures
    output_failures = layers.Dense(output_2, activation='sigmoid', name='failures')(hiddens_layers)

    # Create Model 
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs_, outputs=[output_forecast, output_failures], name=model_name)
    model.compile(loss={
        'forecast': 'mean_squared_error',
        'failures': custom_multilabel_loss},
    optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
    metrics ={
        'forecast': 'mae',
        'failures': 'accuracy'})
    return model
```

and here my docker file

```
# Variables 
ARG WorkingDirectory=/project

# Pull Docker Image
FROM python:3.11-bullseye

# Set up Working Environment
WORKDIR $WorkingDirectory

# Create an "application" directory
RUN mkdir -p $WorkingDirectory/application
RUN export PYTHONPATH=$WorkingDirectory

# Copy Files
COPY . $WorkingDirectory/application

# Update Requirements 
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r $WorkingDirectory/application/requirements/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000

# Start API Server
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python ${ADD_DIR}/application/main.py"]
```

They way I save and load the pipelines :

```
def save_pipeline(*, pipeline_to_saved: Pipeline, name: str) -> None:
    """
    Saved the versioned model and overwrite any previos saved models,
    this ensure there is only one trained model that can be called

    ### Arguments:
        - pipeline_to_save (`sklearn.Pipeline`) : pipeline already trained

    """

    # Versioned file name
    save_file_name = f"{name}_{_version}.pkl"
    save_path = TRAINED_MODEL_DIR / save_file_name

    # Re-write or delete model file
    remove_old_pipelines(files_to_keep=save_file_name)

    # saved
    joblib.dump(pipeline_to_saved, save_path)


def load_pipeline(*, file_name: str) -> Pipeline:
    """ Load Pipeline from trained model

    ### Arguments:
        - file_name (str): pipeline file name

    ### Returns:
        train_pipeline : Pipeline object
    """

    file_path = TRAINED_MODEL_DIR / f"{file_name}_{_version}.pkl"
    print(file_path)
    trained_pipeline = joblib.load(filename=file_path)
    return trained_pipeline
```

I retrained the model twice to ensure that there are no issues with its weight. When running it locally, the model loads, runs, and makes predictions without any problems.

I attempted to move the weight file to the same location as 'api.py' and even tried hard-coding the path to the '.pkl' file.

I am aware that I could split the pipeline and load the model using 'keras.load_weights' and then reinsert the model into the pipeline. However, if it's functioning correctly locally, I wanted to know why it's not working in Docker."

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I couldn't find a simple solution to my problem. Here's what I think was going on: I first trained my model on a Windows computer, but I was trying to use it in a Docker container running on a Linux computer. These two systems don't always get along perfectly (I lack expertise in the intricacies of cross-system compatibility).

I read that **.pkl model files should be used with the same version of Python**(trained on python 3.11.6 and built on python 3.11.6) they were created with, so I made sure of that, but **it didn't fix things** I also tried **zipping the .pkl** file, as some suggested, but that **didn't work either**. Some people said Docker might **have trouble with .pkl files**, but I can confirm that wasn't the problem in my case.

What ended up working for me was a different approach. Instead of just copying the files, I recreated the entire directory structure like I had before. Then, while I was building the Docker container, I trained the model again (inside of docker image). Surprisingly, this solved my problem, and the model worked perfectly in the Docker container. It seems like the issue was because the model was trained on Windows but was being used in a Docker container on Linux (my assumption).

I'm sharing this in case someone else runs into the same issue.
Cheers